# "Driver not found" error message when running PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to do a unit test using  PHPUNIT on a class which utilizes MYSQL using PDO.

The class definition is this:

```
class InputRules{
private $_errors = array(),
        $_db = NULL,
        $_pass = false;  

public function __construct(){

    $_db = DB::getInstance();
}
```

The test script is this:

```
class InputRulesTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test_email_is_empty()
    {
        $Input = new InputRules();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
PDO exception: Cannot find driver.
```

I understand that PDO_mysql module works well with Apache, but not at CLI.

When I execute "php -m", I get:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
hash
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

After reading 2 stackoverflow issues with this kind of problem (one with Laravel and the other one with Symphony.  BTW I am not using any framework), they recommended to install PDO_mysql.

So I executed these 2 commands, (I am using Ubunt 12):

```
    sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
    php5enmod -s cli pdo_mysql
```

I expected to see pdo_mysql with php -m command.
But it did not change and of course I am still getting the error message about driver not found.

I really appreciate any insights to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was changing the host to `127.0.0.1`.  Using `localhost` caused the failure.